# Repository pattern with Entity Framework Entities vs Business Objects

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern

In a code-first implementation of EF, used along with a Repository pattern, should the repository return business objects from the domain model, or simple entities from the data model?

From what I can tell, the point of Repository is to return business objects, not entities, so that you can do work with them. But most of the code examples I find are returning data models instead, which seems like a bad idea to me because what if the data source changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CodeFirst development you can easily use your business object as the data model as well. You can write Ef mappings in a separate DLL to remove the dependency of EF to business model. If you want to change the data source to another one instead of EF you can keep the same Business(domain) classes for that as well.

Comment: Thank you. It took a little more reading for me to recognize this was kind of the whole point of code-first.

Comment: Does this require your data tier to have references to your domain model? Is this Inversion of Control?

Comment: This is not Inversion of control but it seems like domain driven design. You design the domain model first which is shared/common  in the business logic and the persistence/data layer .